# Unable to install Jenkins on Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

Unable to install Jenkins on Ubuntu 20.4 machine getting connection timeout error from mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn:443 (101.6.15.130).

PFB logs:
root@jenkins-server:/etc/rc0.d# sudo apt-get install jenkins -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
jenkins
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 42 not upgraded.
Need to get 71.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 72.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ jenkins 2.319.3
Cannot initiate the connection to mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn:443 (2402:f000:1:400::2). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn:443 (101.6.15.130), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/jenkins/debian-stable/jenkins_2.319.3_all.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn:443 (2402:f000:1:400::2). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn:443 (101.6.15.130), connection timed out
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?